# Requisição JSON vem página inteira

Tags: json, api, laravel-5

Tenho problemas com a `requisição` `JSON`, ela esta voltando o `html` da página inteira sendo que meu pedido é de um `JSON`. Estou utilizando `framework` `Laravel` na `versão 5.2`

Faço minha requisição assim:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_URL => "http://localhost:8000/produtos/" . $id,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => ["Accept" => "application/json"],
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true]);
dd(curl_exec($curl));
```

No meu `controller` que recebo está assim:

```
   if(Request::wantsJson())
   {
        $produtos =  Produto::with('imagens')->where('FlgProdutoVisivel', '1')->get();

        return compact('produtos');
    }
    else
    {
        $produtos =  Produto::with('imagens')->get();
        return view('Produto.listProduto', compact('produtos'));
    }
```

Percebi que ele está caindo no segundo, por algum motivo o `Request::wantsJson()` não está funcionando. Faço isto pois esta mesma `função` retorna a `view` caso que peça a página normalmente e um `JSON` caso faço uma `requisição` `JSON`

Comment: Está caindo no `else` então? ou é uma página de erro, se pode confirmar?

Comment: Esta caindo no else, vem a pagina completa

Comment: a mesma página se caso eu acesse direto do link

Comment: você está fazendo um GET ou um POST?

Comment: A intenção é fazer um get, e estou passando um id para este get

Comment: Tente no lugar o Accept troque por Content-type

Comment: Desculpe as demora @VirgilioNovic mais ainda sim não deu, será que tem haver com o controller, pois se faço a requisição pelo jquery tudo funciona, o problema que para este caso preciso envolver o controller, sera que tem haver ?

Comment: acredito que não está mandando o cabeçalho correto, verifique `$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json",
      url: '/Hello',
      data: { name: 'norm' },
      dataType: "json"
   });` nesse exemplo!

Comment: Aquele código é php, o ajax nao coloquei, pois funciona

Comment: coloque todo o código relacionado, o **ajax** seria importante para entender o porque está entrando no `else`! Pode está funcionando, mas, se não estiver enviando o cabeçalho corretamente pode cair no `else`! (como está acontecendo). Possa ser que também tenha que mudar de `Request::wantsJson()` para `Request::ajax()`!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic O ajax, é outra parte, esta parte estou no controller e faço a requisição, existe outra forma de fazer requisição ?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46712/discussion-between-virgilio-novic-and-renan-rodrigues).

Comment: estamos falando de coisas diferentes...

Comment: Resolveu sua duvida?